# iptables routing all traffic to two different chains?

Tags: iptables, firewall

I'm debugging an iptables setup that I didn't write. This setup is supposed to provide a firewall around some Docker containers (Portainer and Nginx Proxy Manager) running on the router itself, but something is going wrong, and neither Docker container can serve websites to the WAN. `iptables -L -v -n` output looks like this:

```
root@FriendlyWrt:/proc/sys/net/bridge# iptables -L -v -n
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1400K  251M DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
1397K  251M DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 5815  404K ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 2580  116K DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
15447 7639K ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   83  4836 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:9443
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:8000
   29  1740 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:443
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:81
    2   120 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
15447 7639K DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
1397K  251M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
15447 7639K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-MAN (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 8395  519K RETURN     all  --  br-lan docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 2805  167K DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID,NEW
  236 59251 RETURN     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
1388K  251M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1400K  251M DOCKER-MAN  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  236 59251 REJECT     all  --  eth0   docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
1397K  251M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

It looks like at the beginning of the "forward" chain, all traffic is sent to the "docker-user" chain, and then in the next rule, all remaining traffic is sent to the "docker-isolation-stage-1" chain. I would assume that after sending everything to "docker-user," there would be no more traffic left to sort, and the rest of the chain would be completely unused. But it seems like equal amounts of traffic are caught by each rule, and then some more traffic proceeds on to line 3. What is going on here? What is actually being tested in the first two lines of "forward"?

Comment: In addition, the warning `# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them` suggests you might have two layers of rules: some using iptables-legacy, others using iptables-nft (which would be the default). If a rule drops a packet, the packet stays dropped (even if there are multiple chains hooking at the same place).

Answer (score 0):

On mobile and too long for a comment

It seems that you assume that sending a packet to a custom / new chain means that it won’t return from there. That is somewhat incorrect.

The rules in iptables are checked sequentially

Processing stops when a packet matches a rule that gives a final decision on the fate of that packet (usually an ACCEPT , DROP, REJECT  and maybe others I overlooked )

When a rule is to jump to a new/custom chain then :

- that chain is entered
- all rules in that chain are checked sequentially until a final decision is made on the fate of that packet
- If no final decision on the fate of the packet is made:
  RETURN to previous chain

That is what happens in your Chain DOCKER-USER , only a handful of packets match a rule in the DOCKER-MAN chain or the subsequent REJECT rule that result in a final decision. Almost all packets that entered do not meet a final decision and return to the FORWARD chain where they are processed by the the next rule, they will enter the chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1